# Accessing an instance of JTextArea from another class in an array loop. What's the best way?

Tags: java, arrays, swing

I'm having problems conceptually getting my head around how to make my application work.

I have 15 JTextField components and 15 JButton components and 1 JTextArea. I want each button to insert the text inside the textarea from each corresponding textfield.

If you wish to see a graphic to explain this setup - [https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDN7l.png]here[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDN7l.png)

I've managed to get frame.finaltext to the Curriculum subject class, but it is not seen inside the actionPerformed method.

What is the best way of getting a hold of frame.finaltext.append(textfields[i])

TIA 
Adam

```
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.JTextField;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import java.awt.Dimension;

    public class CurriculumSubject extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
    /**
     * This is an class that will hold  details for each subject. 
     */

    // First we want some variables 
    String subjectName;

    public CurriculumSubject (final JReport frame){
        MigLayout layout = new MigLayout("wrap 2");//, debug 4000");
        this.setLayout(layout);
        final JTextField [] textfields = new JTextField[15];
        JButton [] buttons = new JButton[15];

        for (int i=0;i<15;i++){
            String content = "This is a test. " + i; 
            textfields[i] = new JTextField(content);
            this.add(textfields[i], "width 500:700:1000");
            buttons[i] = new JButton(">>>");
            buttons[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                    //Execute when button is pressed
                    String text = textfields[i].getText();
                    frame.finaltext.append(text);
                }});
            buttons[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(10,10));  
            this.add(buttons[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what JReport is, but why don't you provide a method in it to accept a string (or make a sub class of JReport that provides this method):

```
class ReportThingy extends JReport {
   public void addText(String text) {
        finaltext.append(text);
   }
 }
```

UPDATE:

You seem to have many widgets to keep track of. I would recommend introducing a [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern to make your application more manageable. In the short term, you can try making the finaltext widget available to the CurriculumSubject class through a  setter or as a constructor argument.

Comment: JReport is the class that kicks the whole thing off (and holds the JTextArea called finaltext). The image shows what is going on here - http://i.imgur.com/Vnc3C.png - the area on the right is within JReport and is a JTextArea, the tabs are in a TabbedPane class and each TabbedPane is a Curriculum subject. How do I access JReport.finaltext (JTextArea) from the Curriculum instances? Thanks

Comment: Thanks - the setter and getter seems appropriate - I guess I handle that through two different methods. However, by the time I'm in the actionPerformed method, it's difficult to get the instance of JReport - but that's not to say that another method couldn't get a hold of it. Does that make sense? I will have to look at MVC - I'm familiar with it from a little bit of work I did with django some years ago. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm also getting errors java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException - for the array - every time I click a button i is 15, and there are 15 elemnents 0-14. If I move that method, I'm guessing I'll be able to pass it the value of i.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I understood what you wanted. You should define your JTextArea as class variable, so you have one instance of it in one form object, and then you just append text to that object. Example with method:

```
public class CurriculumSubject extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    private JTextArea mainArea = new JTextArea();

    public CurriculumSubject(final JReport frame) {
        MigLayout layout = new MigLayout("wrap 2");//, debug 4000");
        this.setLayout(layout);
        final JTextField[] textfields = new JTextField[15];
        JButton[] buttons = new JButton[15];

        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
            String content = "This is a test. " + i;
            textfields[i] = new JTextField(content);
            this.add(textfields[i], "width 500:700:1000");
            buttons[i] = new JButton(">>>");
            buttons[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    //Execute when button is pressed
                    String text = textfields[i].getText();
                    addTextToFinalArea(text);
                }
            });
            buttons[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(10, 10));
            this.add(buttons[i]);
        }
    }

    public void addTextToFinalArea(String text) {
        mainArea.append(text);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The only problem with this is that mainArea is decalred in JReport - not the CurriculumSubject class. I've passed the instance of the JReport  in the JReport frame  - the real thing I want to get access to is the frame.finaltext (which is a JReport instance which has an instance of JTextArea).

Comment: Do the same thing on JReport class. Declare `JTextArea` there as `final` variable in class varibales list. And then make a method in JReport class:
`public void addTextToFinalArea(String text) {
    mainArea.append(text);
}` and then you can get the text area by `frame.addTextToFinalArea(text);`

Comment: Thanks - another forum that I'm looking at suggests this.getParent().

Comment: this.getParent() not always works. If you put your panel into another panel, then getParent() will return JPanel element and not the JFrame. What I would do (though I don't know if this is the best solution) - I would make one static object of main window and will call it staticly `JFrameClassName.staticInstanceObject`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering that the compiler isn't complaining about your code: You are using a non-final local variable `i` within your anonymous inner `ActionListener` implementation. Try storing `i` in a final variable and use that one in the inner class:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
...
  final int index = i;
  buttons[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
      //Execute when button is pressed
      String text = textfields[index].getText();
      frame.finaltext.append(text + "\n");
  }});
...
}
```